# Why is access to my database very slow?

Tags: mysql, startup

I have a mysql database that used to work perfectly fine, but now it is dead slow on startup. When I type in

```
$> mysql -u foo bar
```

I get the following usual message for about 30 seconds before I get a prompt :

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

Of course, I tried it and it goes a lot faster :

```
$> mysql -u foo bar -A
```

But why do I have to wait so long in regular startup ? This is not a very big database (edit : <10 MB), and data does not seem to be corrupted (everything looks fine after startup). I have no other client connecting to the mysql server at the same time (only one process is shown with the command `show full processlist`) and I have already restarted the `mysqld` service.

What's going on ?

Comment: Based on the information you've provided: who knows?

Comment: @ceejayoz : what kind of other information should I provide ? The problem is I'm stuck and don't know what to look for.

Comment: What kind of system is this running on ? what kind of disk subsystem does it have ? is it busy, or heavily loaded ? is the disk almost full ?

Comment: @Fabian I have the same problem: I used to get fast startup with completion and get slow startup unless I turn off auto rehashing (completion). We haven't changed major version (Percona 5.5).

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem stems from the [**auto-rehash feature**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash)

I tried this out today

At the mysql prompt, I typed

```
mysql> desc outbound_
```

I hit the tab twice and got the following

```
mysql> desc outbound_
outbound_call_id                      outbound_log.ext                      outbound_log.template_id
outbound_log                          outbound_log.failed                   outbound_log.transfer_connected
outbound_log.DealerVoiceProviderType  outbound_log.icallclick_alert         outbound_log.transfer_duration
outbound_log.VoipCallStatusType       outbound_log.isService                outbound_log.transfer_ended
outbound_log.VoipTransferStatusType   outbound_log.lead_id                  outbound_log.transfer_ext
outbound_log.call_duration            outbound_log.outbound_log_id          outbound_log.transfer_phone
outbound_log.call_ended               outbound_log.phone                    outbound_log.transfer_started
outbound_log.call_started             outbound_log.postback                 outbound_log.transfer_status
outbound_log.call_type                outbound_log.recording_url            outbound_log.vehicle_id
outbound_log.called                   outbound_log.remote_call_id           outbound_log_id
outbound_log.callnote_synced          outbound_log.sales_id
outbound_log.dealer_id                outbound_log.scheduled
mysql> desc outbound_
```

Every database and table came up for me to choose

Evidently, mysql client has to read the `information_schema` database. If your mysql instance contains a lot of InnoDB tables, I can see `auto-rehash` stalling the mysql client until it can read `information_schema` database.

Comment: I have very slow startup with 4 InnoDB tables out of about 1000 total tables.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your [mysql] (notice it doesn't end with d) and it will greatly speed up your response time:

```
no-auto-rehash
```

Comment: Would be great if this answer was combined with @RolandoMySQLDBA. This has the "solution", and Roland has all the background info.

Comment: This is the same workaround as providing -A on the command line. I don't think this solves the root cause, considering that it used to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I found the answer to my problem. One of the table from the database cannot be accessed :

```
mysql> show columns from foo;
ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file: './db/foo.frm'
```

The associated `foo.frm` file cannot be read anymore.

```
$> cat foo.frm
cat: foo.frm: input/output error
```

Disk failure :/ Mysql takes so long on startup because it tries to access data from that file.